# How do I look up a user in a Cognito User Pool by a custom attribute?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I am writing an AWS Lambda function in java that should look up a user in my Cognito User Pool by a custom attribute called vendor_id. So far I have the code below:

```
AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
GetUserRequest getUserRequest = new GetUserRequest();
```

But I am not convinced this is the correct approach. It seems the variables of type GetUserRequest cannot look up users in a user pool by anything other than their user name which is not what I need to do.

Any ideas? The Cognito user pools documentation seems sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [amazon doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html)

You can search for any of the following standard attributes. **Custom attributes are not searchable.**

```
username (case-sensitive)
email
phone_number
name
given_name
family_name
preferred_username
cognito:user_status (called Status in the Console) (case-insensitive)
status (called Enabled in the Console) (case-sensitive)
```

Comment: Is it possible to look the user up by sub which is the user's UUID?

Comment: Sub is now present on the documentation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html